# How to get the return value of a method?

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie creating a unit converter.
I have two classes, I have this method in the first class:

```
public String cardName;

public String StartConversion(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConversionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return cardName = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
}
```

I would like to get and use the cardName's value in my second class, so:

```
MainActivity myObj = new MainActivity();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cardName: " + myObj.cardName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But this doesn't work. I know local variables are only accessible inside their scope so I did this instead. They say you can only access it if you make it a class member, that does work but then it has a NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd a) create some class, b) make class members "private", then c) expose those members with [getter and setter methods](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp).

EXAMPLE:

```
public class MyClass {

  private String cardName;

  public void StartConversion(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConversionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    cardName = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
  }

  public getCardName() { return cardName; }
}
```

Then whatever class wanted to access "cardName" would call:

```
String cardName = myObject.getCardName();
```

Look here for more details:
[Java Getter and Setter Tutorial, Nam Ha Minh](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices)

Comment: It should be `public String getCardName()`.  `public getCardName()` is a constructor, and therefore cannot return any value, since there is no specified return type.

Comment: Typo on my part.  It wasn't meant to be a constructor, I wanted to show a "getter".  Which is pretty useless without a return type ;)  Whoops :) - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There exists a train of way to resolve your problem. For instance,

First- the method of StartConversion works to set the card name and then provide a method of getter to access.

Second- Only use the method of StartConversion to return that you want. But you ought to change the code to  `return view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());`, to remove the `cardName =`. The outer class should be called the method to access that you want.

In a word, either call the method to access directly or giving a setter then using the getter to access.